# How to copy a form and rename everything inside?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am copying the AddNewGenreForm form (I want to keep the same control elements and their positions). When renaming the copied form (mouse right click->rename), the other things inside STILL keep the name of the original form instead of AddNewCharacterForm.

[image]

When right clicking on the things I want to rename, I don't get an option. How can I rename those things as well to match the form name? If these elements are somehow a reference to the original form, how can I make it so that they are not/create actual copies without referencing?

[image]

Comment: You should probably build a Template from a Form used as model, then create new instances of your Forms using this Template. A custom Template is shown in the same selector as the predefined Templates installed by Visual Studio. -- Of course, assign names to Controls that don't relate to a specific use case (so you don't need to rename each of them *manually*). -- You can use `Project->Export Template...` to select an Item (a Form here) to save as a new Template.

Comment: I am looking for a way to copy an existing form and its elements fast and easy, so that's not exactly the answer I was looking for, but helpful indeed. If nobody provides an answer, this might be the best alternative solution to my problem, thank you.

Comment: If *the things* you need to rename is just the Form's Name, select the Form in Solution Explorer, press F7, rename the Form and its Constructor, open the Designer file and rename the Form there. If you mean the child Controls, well... the same.

Comment: Thank you very much. What I did was -> Copy the form->Rename it with mouse right click rename -> Go to the file with the constructor -> Rename the class to the form name and rename the constructor to the form name -> Go to the Designer.cs file of the form -> rename the class to the name of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) I found my answer.

1.Copy the form

2.Rename it with mouse right click rename

3.Go to the file of the form that contains the constructor

4.Rename the class to the form name and rename the constructor to the form name

5.Go to the Designer.cs file of the form

6.Rename the class to the name of the form.

**Note that you shouldn't use Visual Studio's rename option when renaming the classes, that would rename your original form's classes as well (because again they share the same name still).**

Answer (score 0):

Those are the method names within that class. You need to rename them in the class file for example AddNewCharacterForm.cs

Comment: When trying to rename the constructor for example, it will rename my original form's constructor -> it acts like a reference, and I don't want that. I want a clean copy of the form, no referencing.